Thunderbolt monitor screen going dark
I am running a 2018 Mac Mini with a 27" Thunderbolt display as the main and a 27" Benq as a 2nd (extended) display. I'm using an Apple TB3 to TB2 adaptor for the Thunderbolt and connecting to the Benq via HDMI. MacOS v14.4.1.
Just for the past couple evenings the Thunderbolt display has been working fine all day but during sessions usually right before bed it has been going dark out of nowhere. I don't think it's actually dropping the connection because the dock, menubar and desktop icons are not moving over to the Benq like they do if I were to disconnect the cable from the back of the Mac, but it's definitely all black and the only thing that bings it back is a restart or disconnecting and reconnecting the cable from the adaptor or back of the Mac. And even after that, in most cases it has stayed on for a minute or 2 and then goes black again.
Mac Fan Control isn't indicating that any internal temps are too high, but the box HAS felt rather hot. I currently have the fan running at full speed constantly and it hasn't gone dark since I made that change (about the past 20 minutes... whereas it was going dark consistently for the 30 minutes before that). Is this a coincidence or does it make sense that the picture would go out if something (video card) got too hot? And in the case of the latter, is this an issue with my Mac's temperature sensing capabilities?

20 mins is too short a time to make a definitive determination as to the cause.  The next time it occurs open up system profiler (hardware report) and see if the monitor, Thunderbolt connection etc are still being recognized

@Allan - so after I posted this last night, I had the fan running full speed for over an hour without any incidents of the TB display going dark. I did just happen a little bit ago this morning though... with the fan running on Auto. And yes the monitor, Thunderbolt connection etc were still being recognized in the system report

Being that this is Thunderbolt, I would be interested in seeing what happens with a TB peripheral (drive, for example) where the fan goes off.  This o is sounding like a component issue with the Thunderbolt system.  Maybe a failing chip

Unfortunately I don't have another TB device to try, but it sounds like if i were to add a TB3 to HDMI adaptor and connect the monitor like that, the issue should go away (if it is a component issue with the Thunderbolt system), correct?

Not really. Thunderbolt is 3 different signals into one:  PCIe, USB and DisplayPort.   If the TB chip is failing converting to HDMI won’t change the fact it starts out as Thunderbolt

oh you meant the thunderbolt system in the monitor, not the Mac Mini. hmmmmmm. ok well I guess i'll have to see how it behaves later tonight after a day's worth of use. Thanks for the guidance thus far.

I meant Thunderbolt in the Mac, but there could be an issue anywhere in the “chain” including the TB 3 to TB 2 adapter.

What's the resolution of the 2nd monitor? In my experience, the 2018 Mini will run the fans up if it's pushing a lot of pixels. FWIW, I used to have one with a TB Display and another display, but I didn't have the 'dark' issue that you report.

2560 x 1440. I don't think it's that as I've previously run that same Benq and 2 other Dell 24" QHDs on this same Mac Mini without issue.
